# Play subproject won't run

Tags: playframework, sbt

I have a SBT project with several subprojects of various kinds.

Some of them are Play projects.

But I can't get them to run

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.7")
```

**project/Build.scala**

```
import play.PlayScala
import sbt._

object MyBuild extends Build {
    lazy val foo = Project("foo", file("foo")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
}
```

After `sbt foo/run` and `curl http://localhost:9000/`, I get

```
! Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1.reload(PlayReloader.scala:89) ~[na:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:122) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:120) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
```

If I change `file("foo")` to `file(".")`, it suddenly works.

Unfortunately, I have multiple Play projects, and this isn't a viable solution.

How do I run a Play server as an SBT project whose base is different than "."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3484).

It has been this way since at least Play 2.2.